# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'storeInfo'

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando usar `useEffect` para uma simples função, mas da erro. Ele não está atualizando a página e salvando a requisição que faço com a função `loadAll` no `useState`. Quando carrego a página o resultado de `storeInfo` é o `null` que é o valor default e não o valor atualizado.

Dá o aviso de dependência *( React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'storeInfo'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps )*

```
  const [storeInfo, setStoreInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const loadAll = async () => {
      let chosenInfo = await Tmdb.getStoreById(635302);
      setStoreInfo(chosenInfo);
    }
    console.log(storeInfo)
    loadAll();
  }, []);
```

Se eu coloco `storeInfo` no array de dependência como pede fica em loop infinito.

```
  const [storeInfo, setStoreInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const loadAll = async () => {
      let chosenInfo = await Tmdb.getStoreById(635302);
      setStoreInfo(chosenInfo);
    }
    console.log(storeInfo)
    loadAll();
  }, [storeInfo]);
```

Não sei mais o que fazer :(
Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, ficarei grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  const [storeInfo, setStoreInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const loadAll = async () => {
      let chosenInfo = await Tmdb.getStoreById(635302);
      setStoreInfo(chosenInfo);
    }
    console.log(storeInfo)
    loadAll();            <=== esta parte modifica o storeInfo
  }, [storeInfo]);        <=== esta parte faz a useEffect rodar quando a referencia do storeInfo muda
```

Sugestões:

- Caso você não precise do `storeInfo` no `useEffect`, remova do `console.log` e do *dependency array*;
- Caso você precise do `storeInfo` no `useEffect`, pode accesar dentro do `setStoreInfo`:

  `setStoreInfo(currentStoreInfo =>({ ...currentStoreInfo, ...chosenInfo}));`
- Caso você precise do `storeInfo` no `useEffect` em geral, coloque o `storeInfo` numa `useRef()`:

```
const storeInfoRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => { storeInfoRef.current = storeInfo  }, [storeInfo]}

useEffect(()=>{
  const loadAll = async () => {
    let chosenInfo = await Tmdb.getStoreById(635302);
    setStoreInfo(chosenInfo);
  }
  console.log(storeInfoRef.current)
  loadAll();            <=== esta parte modifica o storeInfo
}, [storeInfoRef]);     <=== referencia do storeInfoRef nao vai mudar, so o do storeInfoRef.current, que nao vai rodar o useEffect
```